# check if a string is in a file and if it is not append it

Tags: python, file

So i am trying to make Program that checks whether or  not a String is in the file and if its not just append it to the end (in a new line), if its not, it just does nothing.

I already tried w+ but it just overwrites the whole file instead of appending it and if i try a+ its just appends and doesn't check, even though the String is in the file.
So my problem is:

How do manage to check if the String is already in the file and in case its not, append it.

here is an exemplary code:

```
with open("testfile.txt", "a+") as testfile:
    word = "test"
    inhalt = testfile.read ()
    if word not in inhalt:
        testfile.write ("something"+ "\n")
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Did you mean to search for `"test"` but then write `"something"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer such tasks to be done in 2 steps. See below:

```
with open("testfile.txt") as testfile:
    word = "test"
    inhalt = testfile.read ()
if word not in inhalt:
    with open("testfile.txt", 'a') as testfile:
        testfile.write(word+ "\n")
```

Comment: There's no need to use `+` if you're not reading.

Comment: it still only appends to it even if its already in it. But thanks for the fast answer

Comment: It's not possible. Can you please check again? Do you try with the correct word?

Comment: I tested this as well, it works. You're doing something different from both our answers. @dezanos

Comment: ok it seems its a problem in my code i tried it again and now it does nothing. Sorry my bad

Comment: Okay last update the code worked i just had to put testfile.seek (0) before inhalt = testfile.read().

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file in `a` or `a+` mode, you're positioned at the end of the file. You need to rewind to the beginning to read it.

```
with open("testfile.txt", "a+") as testfile:
    word = "test"
    testfile.seek(0)
    inhalt = testfile.read ()
    if word not in inhalt:
        testfile.write ("something"+ "\n")
```

FYI, there's no need for `else: pass`. `else:` is optional, so just leave it out if there's nothing to do.

Comment: its still only appends to it and does not realize its already in there. But thanks for the fast answer

Comment: I just tested it, it worked. When the file contains `test` it doesn't get changed. When the file does not contain `test`, it adds `something`.